# Magento 2: How to get Id and Created Date of an Order in Observer?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

I am using `sales_order_place_after` event in Magento 2 inside `Namespace/Module_name/etc/`. In observer, I am getting order increment id by unable to get order id and created date of Order.

Example:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

$orderId = $order->getId();   

$createdAt =  $order->getCreatedAt();
```

I am unable to get both order id and created date.

Please help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used **sales_order_save_after** event instead of **sales_order_place_after** in my event.xml file and now its working fine. I am getting both Order Id and Created Date also.

Comment: this method will not work, because `sales_order_save_after` event is automatically dispatched after any saving of order entity. thus you will catch this event not only after order placing. Moreover, your method violate service layers principle. I suggested the solution in answers.

Comment: try to add comment to your order or change status, your observer will be called again after saving order

Comment: Yes , You are right @MaxStsepantsevich , but i want this through event and observer only. how to achieve this.

Comment: there are no impediments to create plugin instead of observer, am i right?

Comment: @Max Can you please suggest event which will fire only one time after successfully placing order. It should also fire when placing order from admin screen. I'm using "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" which is work well at frontside but not working at admin side

Answer (score 4):

Try using following event:

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

Observer Code :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class CheckoutAllSubmitAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $orderId = $order->getId();

        $createdAt =  $order->getCreatedAt();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: this method will not work, because `checkout_submit_all_after` event is dispatched only after placing order via magento customer interface. The problem is that order can be placed via magento api or created programmically in system

Answer (score 2):

Event `sales_order_place_after` triggered after payment placing. There is no stored order at this moment. `OrderManagementInterface` save order entity in database after this, therefore there are no db-generated fields such as created_at and entity_id. Use plugin on `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::place`.

Answer (score 1):

Its always good to use `checkout_submit_all_after` observer event for admin and frontend logic so as to get the order data when the order is successfully placed.

Answer (score 0):

order_place_after when executed does not save the data in database that is why you are not getting the order_id for the same. Instead try using sales_order_save_after